# Spring Boot requires spring-boot-starter-security as a dependency for ssl

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I inherited Spring Boot application (version 1.5.8).  I think it reads external `foo.properties` file then creates `Map` object having key/value pair then `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties` consumes it.

When I inspected the properties file, it has many ssl related key/value properties

```
server.ssl.key-alias=<some_value>
server.ssl.key-password=<some_value>
server.ssl.key-store=<some_value>
server.ssl.key-store-type=<some_value>
```

From its pom.xml file I don't see `spring-boot-starter-security` as a dependency though. My assumption is it is ok. Although as newbie, when I went through simple tutorial of Spring Boot in regard to ssl, it has aforementioned lib as a dependency.

I plan to add more ssl key/value pairs like:

```
server.ssl.enabled=<some_value>
server.ssl.ciphers=<some_value>
server.ssl.protocol=<some_value>
```

My question is do I need `spring-boot-starter-security` lib as a dependency or not. I am sure I'd find out once I update/execute the application but I decided to ask first if anyone knows in advance. My initial research didn't come up with an answer I was looking for.

Update:
From its pom.xml, I see following added as dependency. Another attempt of research makes me believe `spring-boot-starter` comes with `spring-boot-starter-security` but I am not positive about this.

```
spring-boot-starter
spring-boot-starter-log4j2
spring-boot-starter-web
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you definitely don't need `spring-boot-starter-security` to enable SSL/TLS in your Spring Boot application.

As described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.configure-ssl), you can enable SSL declaratively by setting the various `server.ssl.*` properties, typically in `application.properties` or `application.yml`.

Refer to the [`Ssl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/Ssl.html) class for details of all of the supported properties. You may also consider checking the Spring Boot common application properties (in special the [server properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server)).

Comment: I appreciate confirmation + sharing valuable information in here.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Spring Boot does not need security for SSL, it's a Tomcat issue. I recommend you to read [this tutorial](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/)